# Use JSON.decode() in dart to instantiate class from json string

Tags: json, dart, angular-dart

By browsing around I did successfully manage to create a class that can "opt in" `dat:convert` by exposing a `Map toJson()` method and can be json-ified with `JSON.encode(myClass)`, more or less like the following:

```
//My dummy class
class MyClass{
  String p1;
  String p2;

  Map toJson{
    return {
      'p1':this.p1,
      'p2':this.p2
    }
  }
}

//so I can do
String jsonString = JSON.encode(myClass)
```

However I'd like to do this even the other way around, like:

```
String jsonString = '{"p1":"value","p2":"value"}'
MyClass instance = JSON.decode(jsonString)
```

But so far I've failed to find a way.
I know I can build a constructor for my class that initialises it from a map, something like:

```
String jsonString = '{"p1":"value","p2":"value"}'
MyClass instance = MyClass.fromMap(JSON.decode(jsonString))
```

However I was looking for a more "symmetric" way using just JSON.encode() and JSON.decode(), is it somehow doable? Am I missing something?

Comment: What about to just hide `JSON.decode` in constructor? And looks like (it is just my opinion) it is better to call `toJson()` explicitly, cause if exception is thrown from it, it does not appear in stacktrace (I don't know why).

Comment: hmmm, for sure I could, but my question was more about knowing why I can opt into JSON.encode() by exposing toJson() and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to encode the class in JSON. `{"p1":"value","p2":"value"}` doesn't contain any information about what class to instantiate. There is also no standard way to create a new class from as string (what library should be used when several contain a class with the same name, ...

As far as I know a reviver can be used for that purpose

```
reviver(var key, var value) {
  // decode manually
}
final jsonDecoder = new JsonDecoder(reviver);
```

but the reviver would need to have some hardcoded logic how to recognize what JSON should result in what Dart class and how it should instantiate it and initialize the properties from the JSON.